# casting ints to str in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to cast an int that's passed to the template through the url, but it says that the `str` function isn't defined.

How do I get around this?

Here's my code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for post in posts %}
    {% set year = post.date.year %}
    {% set month = post.date.month %}
    {% set day = post.date.day %}
    {% set p = str(year) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(day) + '/' + post.slug %}
    <h3>
        <a href="{{ url_for('get_post', ID=p) }}">
            {{ post.title }}
        </a>
    </h3>

        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% else: %}
            There's nothing here, move along.
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Jinja2 also defines the `~` operator, which automatically converts arguments to string first, as an alternative to the `+` operator.

Example:

```
{% set p = year ~ '/' ~ month ~ '/' ~ day ~ '/' ~ post.slug %}
```

See [Other operators](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#other-operators) or, if you really want to use `str`, modify the [Environment.globals](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment.globals) dictionary.

Comment: This just blew my mind.  Jinja2 gets more and more awesome as I work with it.

Answer (score 24):

To cast to a string in an expression, you use `x|string()` instead of `str(x)`.

`string()` is an example of a filter, and [there are several useful filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) that are worth learning about.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `join`:

```
{% set p = (year, month, day, post.slug)|join("/") %}
```