# compare two variables in jinja2 template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

Given I have two variables `{{ profile }}` with a value "test" and `{{ element.author }}` again with the value "test". In jinja2 when I try to compare them using an if, nothing shows up. I do the comparison as follows:

```
{% if profile == element.author %}
{{ profile }} and {{ element.author }} are same
{% else %}
{{ profile }} and {{ element.author }} are **not** same
{% endif %}
```

I get the output `test and test are not same` Whats wrong, how can I compare?

Comment: Try to enter a value of: {{ [profile, element.author] }}

Comment: Accidentally posted. This expression should take representation of variables.

Answer (score 25):

I have the same problem, two variables having an integer value do not equal the same when they are the same value.

Is there any way to make this work in any way.
Also tried to use str() == str() or int() == int() but there is always an undefined error.

**UPDATE**

**Found Solution:**
Simply use filters such as `{{ var|string() }}` or `{{ var|int() }}`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19993378/1232796

Reading the doc it can be found here https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-filters

In your case you would want to do

```
{% if profile|string() == element.author|string() %}
{{ profile }} and {{ element.author }} are same
{% else %}
{{ profile }} and {{ element.author }} are **not** same
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just in case, the new link for the documentation provided in this answer is https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-filters as of July 2023.

Answer (score 2):

`profile` and `element.author` are not the same type, or otherwise aren't equal. However, they do happen to output the same value when converted to a string. You need to correctly compare them or change their types to be the same.

Comment: I just wanted to do some string comparison, how to do that?

Comment: Maybe: `str(profile) == str(element.author)`? Without knowing all the types and other things about your data and code, I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the types of the variables using one of the many [built in tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-tests) that jinja2 has available. For instance `string()` or `number()`. I had the same problem and I realized that was the types.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `|lower` filter:

```
{% if profile|lower == element.author|lower %}
```

That doesn't only cast the variables to the same string type, but also helps avoid mismatch coming from the different ways names might be typed.