# The If equal not working in Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am able to fetch these two values in the Django HTML template : 
    

#### {{ user.get_username }}

#### {{ post.user }}

But when I use them further to compare their values in an IF condition, it doesn't work.

```
 {%for post in post%}
              <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.id %}"><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></a>
              <h2>{{post.content}}</h2>
              <p>{{post.date}}</p>
                {%if user.is_authenticated%}
                  <h3> {{ user.get_username }}</h3>
                  <h3> {{post.user}} </h3>
                    {%ifequal user.get_username post.user%}
                      <form action="{%url 'post_delete' post.id %}" method="POST">
                        {%csrf_token%}
                        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                      </form>
                    {%endifequal%}
                {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}
```

I've also tried {% if user.get_username == post.user %} as well, but it didn't help either.

Please help. I need the delete button only against the posts of logged in user.

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: It's showing the Post Title and Post Content of all the posts. That's it. But no delete button, even though the user is logged in.

Comment: Can it be so that both values are equal but there is difference between the case of some characters? Some are lower case and some are upper case?

Comment: They're exactly the same when I render them like this in the template:
{{ user.get_username }}
{{ post.user }}

Comment: Try `{% if user == post.user %}`. Ifequal is obsolete, you should use the regular if tag.

Answer (score 8):

{{ user.get_username }} and {{ post.user }} are different objects.

If you want to compare the "string" representation of both (thats what you see in the rendered template), you have to convert {{ post.user }} to a string. (I'd convert them both, since I don't know if you user_name is also a string (it should be, though).
Use:

```
{% if user.get_username|stringformat:'s' == post.user|stringformat:'s' %}
```

**Check documentation here:**

[Django Template Tag: Stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)

[Python Conversion Types (I.e. 's')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried solution provided here:

[compare two variables in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623768/compare-two-variables-in-jinja2-template)

```
{% if user.get_username|string() == post.user|string() %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work and gives an error 'invalid filter string()'

Comment: This would only work if the OP was using Jinja templates. Even if they were, it would be simpler to use `{% if user == post.user %}`

Answer (score 0):

{% if user == post.user %} worked for me.
Looks like 'user.get_username' was not working. Just 'user' worked. I wonder why though.

Comment: `user.get_username()` returns a string. `user` is a `User` instance. They are not the same types, so they are not equal, even though `{{ user }}` displays the same string in the template.

Answer (score 0):

`{% if notification.status|stringformat:'s' == 'Approved' %}`
`<td><div class="badge badge-success">{{ notification.status }}</div></td>`
`{% else %}`
`<td>{{ notification.status }}</td>`
`{% endif %}'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).