# jinja dbt macro- unable to match the output

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

I am not able to compare the value stored in result variable even if it is completely same.
I have used trim, checked the datatype, extra whitespace, single quotes, double quotes, without quotes.
if block is not executed as it is unable to match the hash value 6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88
{% set result = dbt_utils.hash(dbt_utils.concat(fields)) %} {%- if result=='6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88' %} null {% else %} {{ result }} {% endif %}
What are my other options here? Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try out the approach as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558872/307901

```
{%- if result|string() == '6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88'|string() %}
  null 
{% else %}
 {{ result }} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi i tried this one but it didnt worked

Comment: So the if statement always become false? What does result look like when you print it?

Comment: this logic i am implementing in surrogate_key macro used in dbt, when all null value are passed in the surrogate_key function it creates hash key against it so i want to pass null instead of hash key and the hash key generated against the null value is '6bb61e3b7bce0931da574d19d1d82c88'. I want to simply compare the result and pass the null value. But in the given logic it is not comparing the hashed value created with the value i have passed and also they are same.