# Jinja: loop to create form fields with same name but the last character

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask and I have a WTF form with 12 input fields named like sold_1, sold_2,..., sold_12.

I would like to generate these fields in Jinja using a loop like:

```
{% for r in range(1, 13) %}
   {{ form.sold_ }}{{ r }}
{% endfor %}
```

or a similar syntax, but it doesn't work.

I solved it in a quite convoluted way as follows:

```
{% set tmp = "sold_x" %}
{% for r in range(1, 13) %}
    {{ form[tmp | replace('x', r)] }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I wonder whether there is a cleaner way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `{{ form['sold_' + r] }}`?

Comment: @dirn: yes, it works casting the integer into a string like `{{ form['sold_' + r|string] }}`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
{% for r in range(1, 13) %}
    {{ form.sold_ ~ r }}
{% endfor %}
```

or, if you want your input fields names to be `sold_nr`:

```
{% for r in range(1, 13) %}
    {{ 'sold_' ~ r }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856576/casting-ints-to-str-in-jinja2) for more detail.

**EDIT**

Using the @dirn and @Libra sugestions the correct answer is:

```
{% for r in range(1, 13) %}
    {{ form['sold_' ~ r] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: tried the first option but instead of giving the input fields it returns only the value of r. Instead it works when written as `{{ form['sold_' ~ r] }} and doesn't require to cast the integer into a string (see my comment to dirn's answer). Thanks